# How to make bold greek letters in Mathjax on Stackexchange?

Tags: support, mathjax

I already know how to make $\mathbf {bold}$ letters, and I know how to make various greek letters such as $\gamma$ and $\Psi$. But how to make any bold greek characters?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Like this $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ `$\boldsymbol{\alpha}$`
For comparison a regular one $\alpha$

Answer (score 12):

`\mathbf{αβγ}` or `{\bf αβγ}` also gives $\mathbf{αβγ}$ compared to $αβγ$ of the normal series.

Comment: But note ... `\mathbf{\alpha\beta\gamma}` does not work.